# PHP headers not being sent to browser

Tags: php, windows, apache, header

I have quite a strange problem with PHP and Apache on my local testing server.  For some reason it keeps stopping sending headers to the browser (I am pretty sure that is the problem anyway).

It's not a case of the old 'output already sent' as it was working fine, had the problem, went away after I reinstalled Apache and is now back again.  Sessions also appear to be broken.  It also gives no errors for 'headers already sent', plus the code works on the live site.

It's not the browser either as I tried different browsers and different machines, which exhibit the same problems.

Even something dumb such as `<?php header ('Location: http://www.yahoo.com'); ?>` doesn't work.

I am running wampserver (latest version) on Windows.  Answers on a postcard.

Comment: Check your Apache error logs, do you see anything unusual there? (also, "Answers on a postcard."???)

Comment: Nothing in the server logs out of the ordinary. :(

Comment: Get more information with a tool like firebug for firefox which will help you to get headers sent to your browser.

Comment: might be a character before your opening PHP tag OR the BOM character.
Please check and let us know (but this should trigger the "headers already sent error") - make sure you have error reporting enabled and your have warnings displayed

Comment: It's not the error - I've checked every concievable place and code with notices on by standard and there is no sign of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using Xdebug on February 2010, it used to have a known issue with generated HTTP headers:

- [0000532: XDebug breaks header() function](https://bugs.xdebug.org/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=00000532)

This issue is now fixed so either switch to a newer version or remove the extension altogether.

Comment: Yes.  Maybe that was the problem.  I've since nuked that install so I can't check but I'll try removing Xdebug if it happens again to see it that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

> Even something dumb such as `<?php header ('Location: http://www.yahoo.com'); ?>` doesn't work.

Try with this instead:

```
<?php header('Location: http://www.yahoo.com'); exit; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check that your PHP.INI has 'display_errors' set to 'On' and while you're at it, make sure 'error_reporting' is set to 'E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE'. Without those, you won't see errors even if they occur.

Secondly, ensure that you set 'output_buffering' to 'Off' in the same file. Just in case.

Finally, there was mention of checking your Apache log. It's also important to check your PHP error log (which is generally a different file again).

Comment: I've got full warnings (and notices) on and there is no alert.

Comment: Do you have display_errors on, too? It has to be explicitly set to actually see those errors, no matter what you've set to show. Also, have you checked the PHP error log as opposed to the Apache one?

Answer (score 0):

A reinstall fixed it, bizarrely enough.